# Treeview Loading hierarchical data

Tags: c#, wpf, database

I have a WPF TreeView. I want the user to be able to create its own folders so he/she can organize the items inside if them (similar to explorer).

What would be the best way to store and load data into the TreeView not knowing what folders will the user create to store his items...

Any example so I test with?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to recognize which files or folders are being affected by user, [System.IO.FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) would help you.